# Different node parent menu for per language

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, navigation

My struggle with Drupal 8 continues as I moved onto i18n settings. I've enabled and configured content translation and now I'm facing issue of menu displaying untranslated pages. Popular suggestions to remedy this is either using Menu manipulator module to filter out untranslated nodes from menu or using different menu per language. I'd like to do the latter, but I can't seem to find an option to select different parent menu for different translations. If I change parent menu selection in English version of a node it will change in other languages as well upon saving. This is curious, as there's no "all languages" next to parent menu label that would suggest that this setting is synched between languages. Or am I supposed to add links to other languages manually by editing menu items?

Comment: Do you have aliases set to be translatable?

Comment: Yep, and it works, I have separate aliases for each language.